# How to create a notifyIcon with functions like application's taskbar button?

Tags: c#, winforms, taskbar

I want a notifyIcon for my windows form application with click functions like taskbar button :

- When the form is on top of other applications; activated, clicking on the notifyIcon must minimize application's window.
- When the form is under other applications; deactivated, but not minimized, clicking on notifyIcon must activate application's window.
- When application is minimized, clicking on the notifyIcon must maximize application's windows.

I've already tried Deactivate event of the form and Click event of notifyIcon, but it seems that in C# Deactivate event of form is compiled before Click event of the notifyIcon.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834257/how-to-detect-if-application-is-activated-by-clicking-in-the-taskbar) I found a way to detect if application is activated by clicking in the taskbar, but I couldn't find the same way for deactivation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) 
        { 
            this.Show(); 
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal; 
        }
        else 
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; 
            this.Hide(); 
        }
        this.Activate();
    }
```

This is a notifyIcon DoubleClick event.